# How to get minimal significant difference for a double?

Tags: java, precision

I have an autoscaling chart, which tries to fit all values from min to max. When I have only one value on the chart, its scale is, of course, undefined. So I need to create some minimal artificial span around this number:

```java
if (span < MIN_SPAN) {
  double amount = (MIN_SPAN - span) / 2;
  this.end += amount;
  this.start -= amount;
}
```

If `MIN_SPAN` is, let's say, `1e-100`, it will work fine when my only value is 0. But if it is 1 or more, it stops working correctly. Probably it is because of the nature of floating point numbers: the difference between 1 and 1e-100 is less than `double`'s fraction precision.

So, question: how to calculate minimal significant span around particular double value?

```java
double getMinSpan(double value) {
// ...
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `Math.ulp`?  `x + Math.ulp(x)` is the smallest `double` greater than `x`, also equivalent to `Math.nextUp(x)`.

Comment: Oh, you are totally right, thanks!

Comment: if you care about the precision try to use BigDecimal Class https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html

it very helpful for date that require higher precision like financial and scientific data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost certainly looking for `Math.ulp`, which returns the "smallest epsilon" for a `double`: `x + Math.ulp(x)` is the next-biggest `double` after `x`.